# Invoke Angular Link from Javascript without DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code...

```
<a ng-click="data.downloadData()" class="button">Download Data List</a>
```

I want to know how I can invoke this through Javascript WITHOUT doing a DOM Click.  I do NOT want to do a getElementBy... or anything like this because it won't work since I'm using Android WebView and it just won't work using DOM methods of clicking it with javascript.

The returned data when link comes back is a direct file response..

```
data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,datahere....
```

In Android WebView you can't do a DOM click and receive a file response back.  Which is why I need to know how to invoke it DIRECTLY without any DOM manipulation like getElementBy...

I need to know if theres any other way to invoke this directly?  I'm presuming its AngularJS

Comment: if your controller has **data.downloadData** function defined, then it will be called on click of link. What do you exactly want?

Comment: `data` should be an object in `$scope`, just manually invoke `$scope.data.downloadData()`

Comment: Would something like `ng-touch` work?

Comment: @SajanChandran  How would I do something like that in say Google Console?  Obviously just copy 'n paste: $scope.data.downloadData() isn't going to work.  How would i manually invoke that?  Would i need to inject some javascript or something?  If so I would assume it would work directly in Google Console since they accept javascript

Comment: @VVK in WebView of Android, just calling the click of a link doesn't actually fire the full response.  I ended up adding a few more data above to try and explain.

Comment: @SajanChandran I'll rephrase my response,  I tried invoking just that and $scope is undefined.  If thats the case and what you say is true, what would be the best way to determine what the object name is if its not $scope?

Comment: I'm curious, what's the context of this?  I mean, what are you trying to do ultimately, in what context.